# shuffle more than 2 array for quiz application?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I need to randomly display questions as well as, corresponding choices and answers. For this I have 3 array,

1) array1 is for questions

2) array2 is for choices

3) array 3 is for answers

For eg:

```
var questions = [
    "q1",
    "q2",
    "q3",
    "q4",
];
var choices = [
    [
        "choice1",
        "choice2",
        "choice3",
        "choice4"
    ],
    [
        "choice1",
        "choice2",
        "choice3",
    ],
    [
        "choice1",
        "choice2",
        "choice3",
    ],
    [
        "choice1",
        "choice2",

    ],
    [
        "choice1",
        "choice2",
        "choice3",
        "choice4"
    ],
];


 var answers = [
    [1,1,0,1],
    [0,1,0],
    [0,1],
    [1,1,1,0],

];
```

I have bellow code which works fine for single array, but I want implement same kind of approach for more than one array.

```
function shuffle(source){
   var l=source.length-1;
   for(var i=l; i>0; i--){
       var itemIndex=Math.floor(Math.random()*(i+1));
       var item=source[i];
         source[i] = source[itemIndex];
         source[itemIndex]=item;
   }
   return source;
}
```

Could you please let me know, what is the best approach to achieve this

Comment: Do you need to shuffle the arrays themselves? You could shuffle an array of question indices, and then look up the corresponding question, choice and answer at ask time. Or e.g. combine the question, choices and answers for each question into a simple structure to keep them all together? You could then shuffle in one go using your method here.

Comment: I agree with Rup's suggestion to combine everything into a single array: `var quiz = [{question: "Highest mountain", choices: [{text: "Everest", score: 1}, {text: "K2", score: 0}, ...]}, ...]`

Comment: No, changing structure is not possible now. Because rendering logic or view rendering code is already done. We have to do by using different arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same approach that you used for a single array to shuffle many arrays. After all, you are not loking at the contents, only at array indices.

First, let's rewrite your function slightly, so that it returns a copy and leaves the input array intact. It also relays swapping to an extra function:

```
function swap(arr, i, j)
{
    var s = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = s;
}

function shuffle(arr) {
    var l = arr.length;

    arr = arr.concat([]);        // Make a copy

    while (l--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * l);
        swap(arr, j, l);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

We can now do all operations on the single array operations on an array of arrays:

```
function shuffleMany(arr) {
    if(arr.length == 0) return [];

    var l = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) l = arr[i].length;
        if (arr[i].length != l) return undefined;
        arr[i] = arr[i].concat([]);
    }       

    while (l--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * l);

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            swap(arr[i], j, l);
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Wherever we used `arr` in the first version, we now use `arr[i]` in a loop. A little care must be taken to ensure that all arrays are of the same length, but other than that, it's straightforward: You use the same swapping index for all arrays:

Use the function like so:

```
var array = [
    ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
    ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
];

var x = shuffleMany(array);
console.log(x[0]);
console.log(x[1]);
console.log(x[2]);
```

Finally, as commenters have already told you, the solution is to keep things that belong together together, i.e. to reorganize your array. Then sorting and shuffling become simple operations on the top-level array.